# Command alias in AIX

Tags: unix, alias, aix

How do we add aliases for commands in AIX. I added below command in my .profile, not working.

```
alias fourth='cd /firstDir/secondDir/thirdDir/forthDir'
```

also I added below.

```
alias killMy = 'ps -aef | grep SomePr'
```

Comment: Does it work from command line? Try this: `alias my_date='date +%Y%m%d'` and then `my_date`

Comment: Tried to logout+login? `ksh` doesn't seem to process `.profile` unless called by `login`

Comment: what shell is this? most likely the error is spaces around the `=` sign. If you edit your .profile, reload it in with `. ~/.profile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, change the single quotes to double quotes.

In your second example, remove the spaces before and after "=" and change the single quotes to double quotes.

Don't forget to re-run .profile after your changes or log out and back in for the changes to take effect.